# MultipartFile name is empty

Tags: java, spring, forms, spring-boot, file

I use multipart-file and when I get it in my current project:
Its name is already empty, **but when I tried different other projects or web-pages it always HAS a filename**.
Here is controller:

```
@PostMapping("/profile/{id}")
  public String add(
          @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
          @PathVariable(value="id") Long id,
          @RequestParam(required = false, defaultValue = "") String filter,
          @AuthenticationPrincipal User user,
          @RequestParam String text, Model model
  ) throws IOException {
    Message message = new Message(text, user);

    if (file != null && !file.getOriginalFilename().isEmpty()) {
      File uploadDir = new File(uploadPath);

      if (!uploadDir.exists()) {
        uploadDir.mkdir();
      }

      String uuidFile = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
      String resultFilename = uuidFile + "." + file.getOriginalFilename();

      file.transferTo(new File(uploadPath + "/" + resultFilename));

      message.setFilename(resultFilename);
    }

    messageRepository.save(message);
    model.addAttribute("messages", messageRepository.findAll());
    model.addAttribute("filter", "");
    return "redirect:/profile/"+id;
  }
```

FreeMarker part with htlm form:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="/profile/${userId}">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="comment">Comment:</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="comment" name="text"></textarea>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="custom-file">
              <input type="file" name="file" id="customFile">
              <label class="custom-file-label" for="customFile">Choose file</label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="${_csrf.token}" />
          <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save message</button>
          </div>
        </form>
```

I tried different browsers and nothing helped.

Comment: Okey, I've just discovered that such problem happened if I use class="custom-file-label" in file input, does anyone have an explanation of this?)

Comment: the problem was here <label class="custom-file-label" for="customFile">Choose file</label> in bootstrap class. Needed just to add 
`<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).on('change', '.custom-file-input', function (event) {
          $(this).next('.custom-file-label').html(event.target.files[0].name);
      });
  </script>`

Comment: Glad you solved it. If you think your solution will help other people in the future, you are welcome to post your solution as an actual answer to the question, with a full explanation (instead of just using a comment, which can be hard to read). You can also accept your own answer, if you wish.